# Throwing back Exception in catch block asks for another try catch block

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to throw Exception Back to calling one. so i am catching the exception and throwing it . while throwing it ask me to surround the statement in try catch block.

```
catch(IOException e){
 throw new Exception(e);//ask me to surround with try catch
}
```

just want to know why is it saying like that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are catching `IOException` while you want to throw an `Exception`. You have to add `throws Exception` to method.

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception{
 try{
   // implementaion

 }catch(IOException e){
   throw new Exception(e);
 }
}
```

Comment: What's the use of catching exception in this example? IOException is a subclass of Exception. Why not to remove catch block?

Comment: @Mikhail Sometimes you may wish to add a custom exception message to the enclosing instance.

Answer (score 1):

You are catching IOException and throwing Exception.You need to throws Exception from method.

Comment: OP might be not interested of `catch`ing any *exception* that extends `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the desired exeption type to be thrown by your method. Please do note that throwing a plain instance of the `Exception` class is a very bad idea.

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception {
  try {
    // Do something that may cause an IOException
  } catch(IOException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
  }
}
```

When you throw an instance of `Exception` (one that is not an instance of any subclass) you can't really do specialized exception handling. The `throws Exception` statement in your method signatures is likely to wind up cascading through your class hierarchy like a disease. Consider throwing a more specific (perhaps custom) `Exception` instance.

In some cases it may be feasible not to handle the exception thrown by the standard Java classes where it is originally thrown, but rather throw it back to the caller using the following code:

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException {
    // Do something that may cause an IOException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature might have not defined to throw an Exception. Add `throws Exception` to your method and it should be working.

Or else

You must only be throwing a sub class of `Exception` but not parent `Exception` which is not acceptable. And hence you need to catch it or throw explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Exception` is [checked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html). You need to rethrow a subclass of `RuntimeException`. Usually `IllegalArgumentException` or `IllegalStateException` are used

```
public void myMethod(){
 try{
   // implementaion

 }catch(IOException e){
   LOG.error(e);
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad file: ", e);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others point out, your method signature needs to state what exception types it will throw.

But more importantly, if you aren't creating a new specific type of exception there is no need to new another exception. Just rethrow the one you caught `throw e;`.

Or if you aren't going to do anything with it, don't even bother catching it, let it bubble up.